# how to redirect a user to wordpress website as soon as user logs-in to my local php website?

Tags: php, wordpress

My folder structure is

- css
- images
- js
- wordpress
- index.php

As soon as the user logs-in to my website (for ex: http://example.com) 
i want to redirect this user to wordpress webpage (for ex: http://example.com/wordpress)

guys please tell me is it possible or not?
if its possible then say how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a redirect in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Comment: can i use session variable instead of cookies in wordpress?

Comment: As long as you've called `session_start()` beforehand - yes.

Comment: Is your entire website the Wordpress site in in the "wordpress" folder or do you also have a site that uses the css, images & js in the root folder? This is important, because the way to set it up will depend on whether you want the entire site operating from the wordpress folder or not.

Comment: @FluffyKitten My entire site is in js css and php. Where wordpress is a sub directory like css.  when i login from outside wordpress the session variable must work inside wordpress. did u got my idea?

Comment: No, I'm afraid I don't. Usually a Wordpress site is entirely contained in the WP install folder (in this case "wordpress"), so what are the css, js and images folders? If the user is logging into the Wordpress site, why do they then need to be redirected to it, and if they are not, how are they logging in?

Comment: @FluffyKitten im not using wp-login, i want the user to login into my own website, after that i want user to redirect to wordpress website. The reason why im doing this becouse wp social login plugin is not giving birthday field. if you know any better idea please share it with me.